Unable to alter the text color within a QTableWidget
I wrote a complex program that utilizes a PyQt6 table. I encountered an issue where I was unable to alter the font color within the table. To troubleshoot, I created a smaller program (see below) that generates a single-cell PyQt6 table containing the letter "A" in red font. However, upon executing the code, the character "A" remained black. Below is the code with comments. Your help is highly appreciated.
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the table widget
        self.table = QTableWidget(1, 1)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Character"])

        # Create the table item with the "A" character
        item = QTableWidgetItem("A")

        # Set the font color of the item to red
        item.setForeground(QColor('red'))

        # Add the item to the table
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, item)

        # Set the table as the central widget of the window
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        # Set the window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Table")

        # Set the window size
        self.resize(300, 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


I cannot reproduce this. It works exactly as expected on Linux using Qt-6.7.1 with PyQt-6.7.0.

Thank you for running the program and confirming that the code is correct. I forgot to mention that I am running it on Windows 11. I will try running it on a MacBook Air and see what happens.

I checked the same code on a MacBook Pro and it worked fine. However, it does not work on my Windows 11 PC. Note that I have written many programs using PyQt6 without encountering any problems changing the font colors of labels or other input/output widgets. Can you run the code on a pc windows 11 machine.

It's most certainly a QStyle issue, but you should try to debug it more accurately. For instance: 1. what happens if you have two colored items? 2. what if you select that item and then click in an empty area of the table? 3. try adding self.table.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex()) at the end of the __init__; 4. add another widget to the main window so that the table will not have focus on start up; 5. add app.setStyle('fusion') right after creating the app; 6. try with setForeground(QBrush(QColor('red'))) (if this works, it may be a PyQt bug). Also, add detailed PyQt and Qt versions.

Thank you for your suggestions for debugging the problem. In my larger program, my intention was to color negative numbers red. Before I read your suggestions, I decided to move forward with my larger program and come up with a workaround where I could color the background of negative number cells in semi-transparent red. The code below worked for this purpose. I will try your other suggestions after completing my larger program and will post my results. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Here is the code:
item.setBackground(QColor(255, 0, 0, 50))  # Set red with some transparency

Tested the code on win 11 (but with pyside2/pyqt5). The letter "A" is red.

Thank you for testing the code on Windows 11. While your findings are helpful, they may not be applicable to the version of PyQt6 that I am using.

@musicamante
I used your suggestion number 5 to add app.setStyle('fusion') right after creating the app, and it works! I appreciate it very much that you took the time to suggest several options and make it work! Thanks a lot!

@Menachem Good, but that's just a work around. You never told us what Qt version you're using (which is quite important), but I have to suppose you're on 6.7.*. After some research, I found out that it is another bug introduced with that branch (it seem to be suffering lots of issues, especially on Windows): the new QWindows11Style replaces QWindowsVistaStyle on Windows 11, and it uses the ButtonText role to draw the item text. While it's common in the windows styles to always use button text color for text, this is inconsistent with what QStyledItemDelegate does and expects: if the index »

@Menachem » has a valid foreground color, set it as the Text palette role. As a temporary workaround, try to create a custom QStyledItemDelegate subclass and set it for the table. In that subclass, just override initStyleOption(self, opt, index), call the base implementation, get the foreground color with index.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.ForegroundRole), verify it's a QBrush, and in that case overwrite the palette accordingly: opt.palette.setBrush(QPalette.ColorRole.ButtonText, color). Then I suggest you to file a bug on https://bugreports.qt.io, including OS and Qt (not PyQt) version.

@Menachem I decided to write an answer, considering that the bug has been reported but it won't be fixed until 6.7.3 will be released. I'd ask you to accept and/or upvote it so that it can be used as a duplicate for similar questions (at least one has already been posted yet). In any case, for future reference, always consider to add proper environment information.

Premise: the problem is caused by a bug that has already been fixed, but since the version containing the fix will not be released for at least a couple of months and other similar questions may raise in the meantime, I decided to provide a related answer.
It's a bug, introduced since Qt 6.7. The default style for windows (previously known internally as QWindowsVistaStyle, named "windowsvista") has switched to QWindows11Style, which is similar to the previous one but also added some changes.
One of those changes erroneously sets the QPainter pen color before drawing the text, based on the ButtonText color role.
By default, QStyledItemDelegate sets the Text color role of the QStyleOptionViewItem if it finds a valid color in the index.data(Qt.ForegroundRole), but when the delegate then tells the style to draw the item, it ignores that color due to the wrong color role used above.
Two bug have been already reported (QTBUG-126543 and QTBUG-126596), and it's already been fixed, but the change will be effective only starting from 6.7.3, which currently is planned for the end of September 2024.
In the meantime, here are the possible options:
Use a different (previous) Qt version
The latest version in the 6.6 branch (6.6.3) doesn't seem to be affected, but I didn't check thoroughly the code and I cannot test on modern Windows. While this may be annoying, the 6.7 branch has introduced other issues (notably on Windows), and unless you specifically need something introduced or fixed in 6.7.*, you could safely downgrade using pip.
Remember that unless you want to actually check for new features, it is always good habit to wait for some releases when a new version of any software/library/OS/etc. is out (a couple of minor version gaps for major versions, or build ones for minor). If you're not familiar with it, always check the available version and consider them carefully based on their release dates and version numbering.
Finally, if you feel lucky and you're expert enough, you can clone the 6.7.3 branch (or even the newer 6.8/6.9) and build it on your own; considering what mentioned above and the fact that you should also rebuild PyQt accordingly, this is obviously discouraged.
Use an alternate style
If appearance and consistency with the OS look is not fundamental in the program, you can switch to another QStyle. Qt always includes the "fusion" style, which is intended to provide cross-platform consistency and full reliability (it's normally used as a fallback or test system, when the default or custom style doesn't behave as expected, especially when using Qt Style Sheets).
You can set the style for the specific widget only, since the delegate always uses the style of the view:
    self.table.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))

This will affect the overall look of the view, but not that of its children: specifically, the appearance of the border around the view and that of its items will be changed accordingly, but not that of the scroll bars or even that of the context menu of its item editors. Setting a different style for a specific widget is normally discouraged, unless it's a QProxyStyle.
Or even for the whole application:
# possibly right before or at least right after creating the QApplication

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QApplication.setStyle('fusion')
    ...

    # otherwise
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    ...

Note: setStyle() is actually a static function, app.setStyle() is equivalent to QApplication.setStyle(), I used app for simplicity. In this case, the change will affect the look (and, to some level, the behavior) of the whole program.
Use a custom item delegate
This is probably the most accurate and immediate approach, and it also provides forward compatibility when the fixed Qt version is finally released and used.
The work around forces the opposite behavior explained at the beginning: changing the ButtonText color of the palette.
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QStyledItemDelegate, ...

class ForegroundRoleDelegateFix(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        fg = index.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.ForegroundRole)
        if isinstance(fg, QBrush):
            opt.palette.setBrush(QPalette.ColorRole.ButtonText, fg)
        elif isinstance(fg, QColor) and fg.isValid():
            opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole.ButtonText, fg)

If you don't use custom delegates, just set the above if the version matches 6.7.0 <= 6.7.2:
from PyQt6.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR, ...

_M, _m, _b = map(int, QT_VERSION_STR.split('.'))
_DelegateFix = _m == 7 and _b < 3


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.table = QTableWidget(1, 1)
        if _DelegateFix:
            self.table.setItemDelegate(ForegroundRoleDelegateFix(self.table))
        ...

Note: if you aim for cross-platform, you should also check the OS and possibly the Windows version (I don't know if the QWindows11Style is also used on Windows 10, but it's quite possible).
If you already use delegates instead, do something similar in the delegate's initStyleOption():
class SomeItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        ...
        if _DelegateFix:
            fg = index.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.ForegroundRole)
            ... etc.

